# Refresh DataTable only if data changed

Tags: javascript, datatables

I use DataTables with serverside = true. I want to redraw my datatable only if data on server is changed. But table.ajax.reload() redraw table on every call.

May you provide the small example?

1. Get data from server
2. Check that data is changed
3. Redraw table with new data

UPD based on comments:

I have simple server side processing datatable. If user change page or sort or filter or anything else there ajax query to server to receive new data and redraw table. But data on server may change. Other user insert new row to database table or change something, for example. I want if this happend data in datable refresh automaticly. But it's rare event. No need to redraw all datable every 10 (or some) seconds. Need to redraw only if something on server changed. Query to server is fast. Redrawing is slow.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing what the gain will be.  Are you having performance or other problems with redrawing the table?  Drawing the table shouldn't be much of a burden with server side processing.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize rendering of the table, or optimize network bandwidth? 

Either way, I don't believe this functionality exists within DataTables.

Comment: I'm trying to optimize renderering. Table is big with pictures inside. On old computers rendering is slow. Check is json strings equals or not is fast.

Comment: Do you have an update timestamp in your DB?  The first thing you will need is to know which rows are being displayed.  One option is to use [rows().ids()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().ids()).  You can use the [selector-modifer](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) of '{page:   'current'}', for example: `$('#myTable).DataTable().rows({page:   'current'}).ids()`.  Then use ajax to query the DB for those `IDs`.  Then use `rows().data()` to get and compare.  Pls provide more details regarding your data and we can help with a more detailed answer.

Comment: I have simple server side processing datatable. If user change page or sort or filter anything else there ajax query to server to receive new data and redraw table. But data on server may change. Other user insert new row to database table or change something, for example. I want if this happend data in datable refresh automaticly. But it's rare event. No need to redraw all datable every 10 (or some) seconds. Need to redraw only if something on server changed. Query to server is fast. Redrawing is slow.

Comment: I understand the question just don't understand enough about your environment to give a better answer.  In one of my tables i use a timestamp to track changes. I periodically check for a newer timestamp and load new data if it changes.  Lets start with the question of how you know if there is a change.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question - my DataTables have buttons, inputs, etc. in them. When a redraw happens issues like de-focusing a textbox or a mis-clicked button can happen. To avoid this, I set my DataTables to only redraw if there is new/updated data from the server.

Here's how:

**template.html**

```
<!-- include lodash _ used to determine json equality -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**script.js**

```
// global variables that are updated with each new ajax reload call:
var last_response = {};
var redraw = false;

// DataTable init:
var table = $('<selector>').DataTable({
  
  // initial settings:
  "columns" : ["<the columns>"],
  ...      

  // override the dataSrc parameter to handle data upon receiving a new response:
  "ajax" : {
     "url" : "<the url>",
     "dataSrc": function(response) {
 
       // compare response to the last response using lodash:
       if (_.isEqual(last_response, response) redraw = false;
       else redraw = true;

       // set the last_response global variable:
       last_response = response; 

       // return appropriately formatted data:
       return data;
     }
  
  // use the predraw callback to determine whether to draw or not:
  "preDrawCallback" : function() {

    // return true to draw or false to skip draw:
    return redraw;

  }
   
});
```